# Why do I have two versions of gtk installed?

Tags: 15.04, gtk, gtk3, ubuntu-studio, gtk-2

Using following command to see what version of gtk my system is using: `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0`

It says:

```
libgtk2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.24.27-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.24.27-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
  *** 2.24.27-0ubuntu1 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

libgtk-3-0:
  Installed: 3.14.13-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.14.13-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
  *** 3.14.13-0ubuntu1 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      3.14.12-0ubuntu2 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

It seems to be saying I've got two versions installed. Why so?

Comment: Simply because you'll have applications, using gtk2 and applications using gtk3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different ABI versions of GTK+.

As mentioned in comments, some things still require GTK+ 2.x, and haven't been ported to GTK+ 3.x. Likewise, you may have both Qt 4.x and 5.x installed, as different applications require different versions.